# Identifying circular dependency between static libraries through script

Tags: perl, linker, graph-theory, circular-dependency

I have a list of binaries that link some static libraries. It was identified that a bunch of these libraries are circular dependent. We never ran into troubles because we enclosed these static libraries between -Wl,--start-group, and -Wl,--end-group

Having understood that this is a bad practice, I'm trying to clean the system.

I've come up with a perl script that tells me how these libraries are dependent on each other, like so:

> libchld.a  depends on libprnt.a, libgprnt.a
>
> libprnt.a  depends on libncle.a, libgprnt.a

and goes one.

Now, I should sort these topologically with each node either pointing upwards or downwards.
And then If I find a set of cyclic dependent libraries while sorting topologically, I will have to enclose **only those**  inside a --start-group and --end-group(than enclosing the entire bunch of libraries) there by cleaning up the system.

Are there some perl modules that does this type of sorting already?

> Sort::Topological 
>   Graph::Directed

are those I'm trying to check. But, they don't appear to handle if the graph is circular.

Comment: You need the [strongly connected components](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Graph#strongly_connected_components) of the dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

> Having understood that this is a bad practice, I'm trying to clean the system.

It's a bad practice because you are not using proper layering, not because it's somehow bad for the linker.

Therefore, cleaning up the link line without re-arranging the libraries into a proper hierarchy with no circular dependencies is a pointless exercise.

And if you do rearrange the libraries, then their proper order will be easy to understand and you wouldn't need to use Perl for that.

Comment: The task isn't supposed to end after passing the libraries in the right order. Fixing the source code is the next action.